# What is the most common word for a student with special duties who helps the teacher?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

What is the most common word for a student with special duties who helps the teacher?

As I googled it, I found a number of suggestions including monitor, prefect and factotum. But which one is the most commonly used term in American and English schools?

Update: In an American movie set in an elementary school, one of the students introduces herself to a new teacher, beginning with the words "as the class factotum, I'd like to say 'welcome to our school'." Is "factotum" a common word for a student representative of his/her class?

Answer (score 1):

Can’t speak for America, but “prefect” is definitely the most commonly understood term here in the UK.

Comment: Thanks. I think the word "prefect" refers to an older student who is given some authority and helps to control the younger students. But what about a class representative who's the same age as others?

Comment: Possibly 'assistant'. I'd probably say 'aide'. The Oxford dictionary defines it as **a person who helps another person, especially a politician, in their job**. Prefects, IMO, help more to control/disciple students. An aide suggests they help a teacher teach.

Comment: _Monitor_ is pretty common as well, particularly in primary schools. Lots of classes have a _pencil monitor_ or a _homework monitor_. However I think the OP may be thinking of a designation common in his or her own country which does not really exist in British and American schools. The nearest equivalent I can think of is the old fashioned [pupil teacher](http://www.molineux.com/gallery/info/PupilTeacher.asp), but these were slightly older children (about 12-15 when most children went to work at 13) who intended to become qualified teachers.

Answer (score 0):

**teaching assistant** of various types here in the states  [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teaching_assistant)

> A teaching assistant or teacher's aide (TA) or education assistant
>   (EA) is an individual who assists a teacher with instructional
>   responsibilities.

Comment: Teaching assistant or aide wouldn't apply to a member of the class with additional responsibilities.

Comment: @user888379 While a Teaching Assistant (TA) would most likely not be taking the same class they are assisting, they *are* usually a student at the same institution.

Answer (score 0):

**Class President**

I know here in the states we have a student council.

> A class president is usually the leader of a student body class and presides over its class cabinet or organization within a student council.

Reference: [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_president)